# Add element linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct str_node {
    int data;
    struct str_node *next;
} node;

void create_list(node ** head, int n);
void display_list(node * head);
void add_e(node ** head);

int
main(void)
{
    int n;
    node *head;

    head = NULL;
    printf("Insert size of list: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    create_list(&head, n);
    display_list(head);
    add_e(&head);
    display_list(head);

    return 0;
}

void
display_list(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list.");
    }
    else {
        while (head != NULL) {
            printf("DATA: %d\n", head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }
        puts("null");
    }
}




void create_list(node **head,int n){
    node *new,*tmp;
    int num,i;
    *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(*head == NULL){
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Insert element 1: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        (*head)->data = num;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        tmp = *head;

        for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
            new = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(new == NULL){
                printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
                break;
            }
                else{
                printf("Insert element %d: ",i);
                scanf("%d",&num);
                new->data = num;
                new->next = NULL;
                tmp->next = new;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}


void
add_e(node **head)
{
    node *new;
    int num;

    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Insert element at the beginnig: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        new->data = num;
        new->next = NULL;
        while ((*head)->next != NULL) {
            *head = (*head)->next;
        }
        (*head)->next = new;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why after using the `add_e()` function, the `display_list()` function  gives to me only the last two number of the list. The `add_e()` fucntion  should be add an element at the end of the list. What am i doing wrong?

Edit: Added `create_list()` function so you can understand better but now it says to me to add more details so I'm writing something.

Comment: I've cleaned up the code enough so it compiles, but it is missing the definition of `create_list`, so although it now compiles, it has a link error. Please edit your question and add the missing definition, so we have a version that can be downloaded, compiled, linked, and run/tested.

Comment: Your code is missing some stuff, namely the `create_list` definition, and `main` , which I assume is the code below the functions declaration, if that's the case, a problem there is that u are using uninitialized `n`, to what end remains to be seen.

Comment: Without seeing the calling code I can't be certain, but I suspect **you're passing the actual `head` variable by reference** to `add_e()`, so when you iterate to the end of the list *using that variable,* you lose the earlier nodes forever. Pass by value.

Comment: I added the missing part.. So i have to pass (*head) instead of (**head)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`, `n` is *unitialized*, so you'll get random/bad results.

The `add_e` should *not* use `*head` in the `while` or even do a `while`. The `printf` says "insert at beginning", which is different/simpler. This is what I've currently coded up/fixed.

You'd want to use a loop, *if* you [really] wanted to insert/append to the *end* of the list. But, the loop would still be incorrect, because you *don't* want to advance `head` when finding the end.

I've also fixed the `printf` for prompts and `scanf`

Here's a refactored/fixed version of your code with the bugs annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct str_node {
    int data;
    struct str_node *next;
} node;

void create_list(node **head, int n);
void display_list(node *head);
void add_e(node ** head);

int
main(void)
{
    int n;
    node *head;

    head = NULL;

// NOTE/BUG: n is unitialized
#if 1
    n = 5;
#endif
    create_list(&head, n);
    display_list(head);

    add_e(&head);
    display_list(head);

    return 0;
}

void
display_list(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list.");
    }
    else {
        while (head != NULL) {
            printf("DATA: %d\n", head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }
        puts("null");
    }
}

void
create_list(node **head, int n)
{
    node *new,
    *tmp;
    int num,
     i;

    *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Insert element 1: ");
#if 1
        fflush(stdout);
#endif
#if 0
        scanf("%d", &num);
#else
        scanf(" %d", &num);
#endif

        (*head)->data = num;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        tmp = *head;

        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            new = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (new == NULL) {
                printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Insert element %d: ", i);
#if 1
                fflush(stdout);
#endif
#if 0
                scanf("%d", &num);
#else
                scanf(" %d", &num);
#endif
                new->data = num;
                new->next = NULL;
                tmp->next = new;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void
add_e(node **head)
{
    node *new;
    int num;

    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Insert element at the beginnig: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf(" %d", &num);

        new->data = num;
        new->next = NULL;

#if 0
        while ((*head)->next != NULL) {
            *head = (*head)->next;
        }
        (*head)->next = new;
#else
        if (*head == NULL)
            *head = new;
        else {
            new->next = *head;
            *head = new;
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

In `add_e`, because I couldn't be sure if you wanted to insert at beginning of list [based on the `printf`] or at the end [based on the code], I created a version that is cleaned up a bit more and demonstrates *both* types:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct str_node {
    int data;
    struct str_node *next;
} node;

void create_list(node **head, int n);
void display_list(node *head);
void add_begin(node **head);
void add_end(node **head);

int
main(void)
{
    int n;
    node *head;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    head = NULL;

    printf("Enter initial number of list elements: ");
    scanf(" %d",&n);

    create_list(&head, n);
    display_list(head);

    add_begin(&head);
    display_list(head);

    add_end(&head);
    display_list(head);

    return 0;
}

void
display_list(node *head)
{
    node *cur;

    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list.\n");
    }

    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        printf("DATA: %d\n", cur->data);
}

void
create_list(node **head, int n)
{
    node *new, *tmp;
    int num, i;

    tmp = *head;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        new = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new == NULL) {
            printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
            break;
        }

        printf("Insert element %d: ", i);
        scanf(" %d", &num);

        new->data = num;
        new->next = NULL;

        if (*head == NULL)
            *head = new;
        else
            tmp->next = new;

        tmp = new;
    }
}

// add_begin -- insert at before head of list
void
add_begin(node **head)
{
    node *new;
    int num;

    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Insert element at the beginning: ");
    scanf(" %d", &num);

    new->data = num;
    new->next = *head;

    *head = new;
}

// add_end -- add to tail/end of list
void
add_end(node **head)
{
    node *new;
    node *tmp;
    node *tail;
    int num;

    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Append element at the end: ");
    scanf(" %d", &num);

    new->data = num;
    new->next = NULL;

    // find the tail
    tail = NULL;
    for (tmp = *head;  tmp != NULL;  tmp = tmp->next)
        tail = tmp;

    if (tail != NULL)
        tail->next = new;
    else
        *head = new;
}
```